# Программное нажатие клавиши в окне

Tags: delphi

Как эмитировать нажатие клавиши в определенное окно. Например, нажатие клавиши `F1` в окно "Мой компьютер"?

Answer (score 1):

Например с помощью WinAPI отправить сообщение окну. На Delphi это будет выглядеть так:

```
var
wnd:Hwnd;
begin
 wnd:= FindWindow(nil, PChar('Мой компьютер'));
    if wnd>0 then
      begin
        SendMessage(wnd,WM_KEYDOWN,VK_F1,0);
        Sleep(200);
        SendMessage(wnd,WM_KEYUP,VK_F1,0);
      end
     else
showmessage('Window not found');
```

end;

Answer (score 0):

Вроде в составе дельфи есть файлик sendKeys.pas там это реализовано

Answer (score 0):

Если окно содержит фокус ввода, то имитация нажатия клавиши производится с помощью вызова SendKeys:

```
uses SendKey, KeyDefs;
```

и

```
SendKeys('{F1}');
```

для эмуляции нажатия клавиши F1. Если окно не содержит фокус ввода, то сначала надо его найти (FindWindow), затем поднять наверх SetForegroundWindow (это WinAPI).